# Do these stacks share all the same fixtures? Can I remove one?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Below you'll find a lovely (crude) illustration of my stacks for the kitchen (main floor) and laundry room (basement).

Fixtures are:

Kitchen (all on red stack):

- Sink
- Garbage disposal
- Dish washer

Laundry room:

- Shower
- Sink
- Washing machine
- Kinetico water softener

My questions are:

1. Is it just me or do both the red and the green stacks vent all 7 fixtures? It looks like the pump pumps the water up but those gases would then travel up the red stack, thus venting all the basement fixtures into the kitchen stack.
2. Could I eliminate the red stack and T branch off where the pink arrow is pointing? If not, why? Too many fixtures on one stack?
3. If I cannot remove the red stack is there something I can do to make it not smell? The vent circled in red in the kitchen smells pretty damn bad (occasionally) when I run the washing machine or shower. I think this led me to believe that even the basement fixtures were being vented to the red stack and into the kitchen. (I believe it's an air admittance valve, this one called Nova Vent, the basement is an Oatey Sure Vent)

[image: kitche and bathroom plumbing stacks]